# what is blocking and non-blocking web server, what difference between both?

Tags: webserver

I have seen many a web framework provide a non-blocking web server, I just want to know what it means.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using a **blocking** socket, execution will wait (ie. "block") until the full socket operation has taken place.  So, you can process any results/responses in your code immediately after.  These are also called *synchronous* sockets.

A **non-blocking** socket operation will allow execution to resume immediately and you can handle the server's response with a callback or event.  These are called *asynchronous* sockets.

Answer (score 55):

a blocking web-server is similar to a phone call. you need to wait on-line to get a response and continue; where as a non-blocking web-server is like a sms service. you sms your request,do your things and react when you receive an sms back!

Comment: Who is the caller/initial smser?  The client or the server?

Answer (score 6):

Non-blocking generally means event driven, multiplexing all activity via an event driven system in a single thread, as opposed to using multiple threads.

Comment: Why does this answer differ from the others? Are multi-threading and synchronous sockets related? How?

Answer (score 1):

Blocking server uses a dedicated process/thread to handle a single income request.

In non-blocking server a process/thread is able to handle multiple requests at the same time. It could be possible because usually most of the time a request is in a state of waiting of a result of I/O operation (reading file, waiting result of a db query, waiting result of http request to some web-service etc.). So while one request is in the "wait" state the process/thread can handle other request which is in "ready" state.

From point of view programming a handler of a blocking server is simple. It just process input request by a dedicated process/thread. On the other hand a handler in a non-blocking server should somehow notify the process/thread in which state it is either in waiting for I/O result or it received an I/O result and ready to continue processing.